# How to run php function with params thought shell?

Tags: php, shell, terminal, cgi

I want to execute php function with params or eventually `$_GET` params. I would enter number in the terminal and the value will be passed in my script.

For example, if I have function which devides numbers, for example, `$a` and `$b`, I want to enter in the terminal values of `$a` and `$b` and function to recalculate. I read that is nessessary PHP CGI but I couldn't execute the script.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and LAMPP.

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: `$_GET` params don't exist at the command line (the `GET` method is an http construct, so only exists in PHP when using a web sapi), you need to use [$argc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) or [getopt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) instead

Answer (score 1):

The arguments in php are received in `$argv`. To test, create a simple script like this:

```
<?php
print_r($argv);
?>
```

And execute it on your terminal:

```
$ php test.php X 2
Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => X
    [2] => 2
)
```

As you can see, the first argument (`$argv[0]`) is the script name. The total number of arguments passed to the script will be `$argc`.